# Website turns smaller in Opera and Chrome in a 1920x1080 LCD monitor

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, opera

This is my first question here. I often got help from other questions already posted here by searching Google but this time I must resort to the Ask Question.

I am building a website and using all the major browsers for testing. All seems working fine in CRT/LCD monitors with a min 1024x768 rez and up to 1280x1024.

However, when I tested my website files in a wide LCD with greater rez using all browsers, the result was this:

In a 1920x1080 LCD using FF, IE and Safari it all worked properly. When I used Opera and Chrome (latest versions) I've noted that the website display got smaller. I checked all the browsers Zoom and they were all 100%. But for an equivalent view like in FF and IE, I found that raising the Zoom percentage for 125 it all looked fine with Opera and Chrome.

Why this behaviour? Why Opera and Chrome doesn't work equally to FF, IE and Safari with a 100% Zoom?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to nail down the problem without more information. Can you create a simplified example on jsfiddle.net? (Sometimes defining the problem for others helps you figure it out on your own.) Does your CSS target specific resolutions? Do other sites show the same symptoms for you, or just your site? Are you testing with windows maximised, or in full-screen mode; vanilla installations, or customised with add-ons that might change the amount of screen real-estate?

Comment: Hi aaamos, thanks for answering. My CSS does not specify any resolutions and no full-screen modes, vanillas or extra add-ons are being applied. It displays well on FF, IE and Safari but to see the "original" display in Opera or Chrome, I must switch the percentage for 125%. I have in my CSS the following: html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

Answer (score 1):

I used this and worked :)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  body {
    zoom:125%;
    }
}
```